# high validation loss and abnormal predictions outside normalized range in KeyPoint Detection Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

"Hello everyone,

I am currently working on a KeyPoint Detection Network, the goal is to predict the correct x and y value for each keypoint. I have encountered an issue with the predicted values. I have successfully normalized the data, ensuring that the keypoints' values fall within the range of 0 to 1. To verify the data i am feeding the model are correct (including validation, training, and test sets), I used the function sk.show_keypoint, and they are what I am expecting.

However, I am experiencing a problem where the network predicts values that are outside the expected range. For example, I get predictions like

```
[[ 1.5571796 -1.5212063 -1.5553608 1.5570908 -1.5887384 1.5819738 1.5625474 -1.5526751 -1.5711758 1.5739774 1.5815413 1.5541165 -1.5574389 -1.8088359 -1.5553869 1.5725775 1.5559578 -1.5867838 1.5536412 1.61665 -1.5670778 -1.5944076 1.5860206 1.5846121 -1.5490519 1.5757351 -1.5185088 -1.5199621]]
```

, which are not within the expected range of 0 to 1.

I have already experimented with different learning rates (LR), and the values I am currently using are:

- Initial LR (lr_i) = 0.88
- Final LR (lr_f) = 0.01
- Decay factor (decay_f) = 39

Despite adjusting the LR, the issue persists. I am seeking your assistance in understanding why this is happening and how I can resolve it.

Here is a snippet of my code for reference:

```
from keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.data import TFRecordDataset
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, schedules
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping , LearningRateScheduler
import glob
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

import lib.deserialize_example_cnn as des
import lib.show_keypoints as sk

def main(lr_i,lr_f,decay_f,bst):
    # parameters
    fs= " lr_i:"+str(lr_i)+"  lr_f:"+str(lr_f)+"  decay_f:"+str(decay_f)+"  bst:"+str(bst)
    print(fs)
    shape_image = 500
    input_shape = (shape_image,shape_image,1)
    num_classes = 28
    files_out_names = "early_stopping_shuffle_low_low_lr"
    
    dir_in = "C:/risorse/PDL/dataset_mini/"
    model_path = "C:/risorse/PDL/"
    num_epochs = 5
    batch_size_training = bst

    initial_learning_rate = lr_i
    decay_step = num_epochs*batch_size_training*decay_f
    end_learning_rate = lr_f

    dir_in_training = dir_in + "training/"
    dir_in_validation = dir_in + "validation/"
    dir_in_testing = dir_in + "testing/"

    # loading training dataset
    #print("dir_in_training:"+dir_in_training)
    filenames_train = glob.glob(dir_in_training + "*.tfrecord")
    ds_bytes = TFRecordDataset(filenames_train)
    dataset_training = ds_bytes.map(des.deserialize_example)
    dataset_training = dataset_training.shuffle(5340, reshuffle_each_iteration=True) #5340 is the seed

    # Visualizing training images
    xi = 0
    for image, label in dataset_training:
        #print(label)
        if sk.prob(1):
            draw_label = sk.inversion(label)
            sk.show_keypoints(image,draw_label,"cnn"+ str(xi)) #this is the function I've used to check the keypoint are correct
        xi += 1

    # loading validating dataset
    filename_validate = glob.glob(dir_in_validation + "*.tfrecord")
    ds_bytes = TFRecordDataset(filename_validate)
    dataset_validation = ds_bytes.map(des.deserialize_example)


    # batching data
    dataset_training = dataset_training.batch(batch_size_training)
    dataset_validation = dataset_validation.batch(1)

    # Model definition

    model = Sequential()

    resnet_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_shape=input_shape)

    model.add(resnet_model)
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes))

    lr = schedules.PolynomialDecay(
        initial_learning_rate,
        decay_step,
        end_learning_rate
    )

    callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',mode="min",patience=2,restore_best_weights=True)
    lr_callback = LearningRateScheduler(verbose=1)
    optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr)

    # Compiling model
    #model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=Adam(learning_rate = initial_learning_rate))
    model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer=optimizer)

    # Fit model
    print(fs)
    history = model.fit(dataset_training, epochs=num_epochs, batch_size=batch_size_training,callbacks=[lr_callback , callback],validation_data = dataset_validation,use_multiprocessing=True)

    model.save(model_path + "model_" + files_out_names + ".h5",save_format='h5')

    # plot graph
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(len(history.history['loss'])):
        x.append(i)
        y.append(history.history['loss'][i])


    # loading test dataset
    filename_test = glob.glob(dir_in_testing + "*.tfrecord")
    ds_bytes = TFRecordDataset(filename_test)
    dataset_test = ds_bytes.map(des.deserialize_example)

    # batch dataset
    dataset_test = dataset_test.batch(1)

    # Evaluate model on test dataset
    print("Evaluate on Test Dataset")
    eval_loss = model.evaluate(dataset_test)

    print("Evaluation loss:", eval_loss)
    return eval_loss
```

I though modify the LR would solve the problem but the best value of val_loss and test_loss i got was 4.26 on test. I train it for 5 epoch:

```
Epoch 1/5
700/700 [==============================] - 54s 69ms/step - loss: 298610458624.0000 - val_loss: 4.2689
Epoch 2/5
700/700 [==============================] - 48s 68ms/step - loss: 4.1115 - val_loss: 4.2684
Epoch 3/5
700/700 [==============================] - 49s 68ms/step - loss: 4.1110 - val_loss: 4.2678
Epoch 4/5
700/700 [==============================] - 49s 69ms/step - loss: 4.1102 - val_loss: 4.2667
Epoch 5/5
700/700 [==============================] - 49s 68ms/step - loss: 4.1089 - val_loss: 4.2652
```

Comment: Please clean up your code; it's really hard to find what's important within all the comments and unrelated parts.

Comment: @doneforaiur done it. Hope now is more readable

Comment: Much better, thank you! Is it possible for you to try lowering the learning rate even further? Additionally, could you provide some training and validation loss graphs?

Comment: @doneforaiur the result on val_loss tend to be always static that's why i don't train it for many epoch. Edited the post

Comment: But in reality, it's not static. You start with 0.88 (which is way too high for most applications) and end up with 0.01 in just 5 epochs. I also noticed something weird, this is not a regression problem, but a classification problem. Could you try `categorical_crossentropy` for your loss function instead of `mse`?

Comment: LR decay use this "decay_step = num_epochs*batch_size_training*decay_f". so i don't think lr reach 0.01 in just 5 epochs. I meant that loss is pretty static going from 4.2689 in 1st epoch to 4.2652 in epoch five. Also is a keypoint detection not a classification problem

Comment: So `decay_step` is `5*`1*37 which means you reach your `lr_f` in 185 steps, which is way less than one epoch. I would avoid using decaying learning rate until I've found a suitable learning rate for the problem. Still, I think you have used wrong kind of loss function for ResNet.

Answer (score 1):

You have a classification problem, so doneforaiur is right to suggest `categorical crossentropy` for your loss function.
Also, you have no activation function for your last layer:

```
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
```

You can get classification predictions in [0, 1] with the `softmax` activation function like:

```
model.add(Dense(num_classes), activation='softmax')
```

If your target data is not one-hot encoded, but label-encoded you can use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as your loss function.

If you don't want to use a softmax activation function with your last layer, you can leave it without the activation and use `loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)` in model.compile().

Edit: If it is no classification problem, and you need your output in range (0, 1), use a `sigmoid` activation function. Beware that 0 and 1 are never reached here. It is also not very common to do that, normally you just let the network figure it out and go with a linear activation, as with your example.
Generally speaking, without an activation function, your network is not restricted to any kind of range for its outputs. With the correct activation function, you limit the range of the output values. With regression, you normally don't want this but you can try and look if `sigmoid` works out for you.
It can also be a problem that you try to let the network predict 14 variables at one, of which 14 are pairwise connected (x and y coordinate). That's a lot. You could try to reduce the number of points the network has to predict.

Comment: if it is a classification problem i should have infinite class becase the number between 0 and 1 are infinite

Comment: Not really, the numbers between [0, 1] are not distinct classes but probabilities. What's happening with softmax is, that it scales all input (the output of your last layer) between 0 and 1, with the sum of all outputs = 1.
To illustrate, let's say your network output is `y=[-1., 0.5, 2., 10., 2.]`. This means you have 5 different classes, because there are 5 numbers. softmax(y) would be `[1.668e-05, 7.479e-05, 3.352e-04, 9.992e-01, 3.352e-04]`, with `sum(softmax(y)) = 1`. Each number represents the class probability. Because `9.992e-01` is the largest number, class 3 would be the prediction.

Comment: You could make the prediction for class 3 without softmax, as 10 is still the largest number in y, but `CategoricalCrossentropy` needs probabilities as input, which softmax provides. If you use `from_logits=True`, `CategoricalCrossentropy` uses softmax under the hood for itself.

Comment: @dante, please try what is being recommended. You are just asking whole other questions. It is a classification problem, you have a `num_classes` variable.

Comment: @doneforaiur  I have to find 14 points in my pictures (each point has an x and a y value), so I have to set the value between 0 and 1 for each number in between. 'num_classes' is just the name I gave to the variable to indicate that I have 28 points (14 * 2). I can't really understand how this can be a classification problem, and if it is, please explain it to me because I think you guys didn't really read my post.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but then it's just a bad variable name. Don't call it classes, when it's no classification problem. Most of the time it's not trivial for people to read other people's code and get their idea and goals, and this is not helping.
I edited my answer above for a regression problem. You should still look out for your learning rate, 0.8 is extremely high for Adam.